# Grails soap webservice wslite No such property exception

Tags: web-services, grails, soap, groovy

I want to invoke soap service in Grails using the plugin called wslite.

I just copy the sample from the official doc. The code is:

```
withSoap(serviceURL: 'http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/US/Dates/USHolidayDates.asmx') {
   def response = send(SOAPAction: 'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/GetMothersDay') {
      body {
         GetMothersDay(xmlns: 'http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/US/Dates/') {
            year(2011)
         }
      }
   }
   println response.GetMothersDayResponse.GetMothersDayResult.text()
}
```

However I got the exception:

```
No such property: GetMothersDay for class:xxxx
```

Comment: What are you expecting from the as is example?

Comment: What are you talking about?